# Tooltip over range slider

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, slds

I'm currently working with a range slider that has steps on it. Is there a way to do a tooltip above each step? Here's the current slider code. So at every step I need to put the tooltip over the slider indicator.

```
<lightning:slider step="250" 
                      value="{!v.goal.Short_Term_Goal_Amount__c}"
                      onchange="{!c.handleShortTermRange}" 
                      min="0" max="2000" 
                      label=""/>
```

Comment: Hi, Ryan, and welcome to SFSE! What's the purpose behind the tooltip on a slider? Why couldn't you use a Path or something? What effect are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/229936/edit) your question instead of adding the info into the comments.

Answer (score 3):

I'm completely confident you can do it. If you're using a built in component I'd look up the definition for the component to see if it has any built in attributes.

Otherwise, you can use [this site here](https://lightningdesignsystem.com/components/slider/) to build out the component manually. This will allow you to use javascript to add the tool-tips you need.

[Using HTML in lightning components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_html.htm)

Since SFDC converts HTML tags into components you might be interested in this article [about creating components dynamically](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_dynamic_cmp_async.htm).

### JavaScript disclaimer

We do to an extend provide Javascript support as it specifically applies to SF such as linking up elements to controller functions, handling events, api usage, etc; however, there are some items that we can't provide extensive support for. For advanced JS support you can reach out to [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/)